# Why does one td element take up more space than another

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

If I have a table like so:

```
<div class="container">

  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Test Title</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Assignment</th>
        <th class="text-center">Count</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="text-center">
        <td>Test Assignment</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

The `td` element that contains `Assignment` is much wider than the `td` element that contains `Count`.  This looks unpleasing because now the title seems off-centered (even though it is centered), b/c that `td` element is taking up too much space.

How can I fix that?

Here is a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Ur6uerjqH5).

Comment: because you haven't given the columns a width, the browser renders the width based on the cell contents.  As the first column has more text inside it, it is assigned more width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[updated bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ALpQkVboC3)
 add `class="col-md-6"` to your `<td>`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Test Title</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Assignment</th>
        <th class="text-center">Count</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="text-center">
        <td class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">Test Assignment</td>
        <td class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define the size of the table

```
<div class="container" width="196">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" class="text-center">Test Title</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="text-center">Assignment</th>
<th class="text-center">Count</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="text-center">
<td>Test Assignment</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```